# Forcing Language

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Does anyone know of a reference that explains the concept of forcing by fixing a forcing language that has a (I believe unary) predicate and does not mention the forcing poset?

For example, Kunen's development will have no one fixed forcing language. The forcing language will change depending on the particular poset with which you are trying to force,

(I realize that the question is vague and I apologize for it)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: The way Kunen does it, he defines a class of languages, one each for each forcing poset. Is there a way to not define so many forcing languages but just have one forcing language with a predicate that'll take care of the messy details? I'm pretty sure it has been done and it would probably be more elegant than having different languages for each of the posets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Do you think this meets the criteria for mathoverflow? I once posted a very easy question before I figured out the standards for questions posted there?

Comment: I'd say it's borderline. Leave it here for a week or so. If no one posts an answer, you can ask it to be migrate to MO, or re-post it there (and be sure to include the fact that you posted here and waited a week or so, with link).

Comment: ok. thank you for the help!